# DDD: Should we bypass domain models sometimes?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, ddd-repositories, clean-architecture

I work on a project where we try to apply DDD to the best of our knowledge. We also use CQRS and onion architecture.
We have aggregates for which we have repositories. For each post we use a factory service and then persist the result using the aggregate repository, for put we call the repository without using any factory of course. 
So far so good!

Now, here to me is smth fishy but I am curious to hear other opinions: **For some gets, instead of using the domain models, because of performance concerns, we do not want to load the whole aggregate just to get 5 fields for example, so we bypass the domain models and we use a separate repository just for that CQRS query. This repository( we call it search engine) returns a DTO(not a domain model as the normal repositories return). We bypass the whole domain and everything happens at Application layer.**

**Is this normal? Is this smelly? Does this look like our domain models are not properly designed? Is this bad practice? Does this align with DDD and clean architecture?**

I am curios to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal, in modern designs, to bypass the domain model when responding to a safe request.

Historically, when Evans describes the implementation patterns, the "database" is just some implementation detail hiding behind the repository abstraction.  So access to the data is constrained by what is provided by the repository interface; that meant aggregate roots, or collections of aggregate roots.

You can see this in the [Cargo Booking sample](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/interfaces/booking/web/CargoAdminController.java#L71), where the repository provides a list of aggregate roots, and then that list of roots is transformed into a list of DTOs.

I attribute this to the fact that Evans was working on Java circa 2003; there's a bunch of implied constraints that have no more real justification than "that's what we thought good OO design looked like" at that time.

To be fair, it's not completely unreasonable that you would want to base the read model on the data that will be used by the write model.   The write model is expected to change in response to the needs of the business; if we want the views to be representative of the model, then the view will need to make the same changes, and it is a lot easier to ensure that if the one depends directly on the other.

With the introduction of distributed domain driven design (which eventually became command query responsibility segregation), we came to abandon the notion that "aggregates" support safe queries.  If you want to query data, you ask a database -- that's what databases are *for*.

The single responsibility of the domain model becomes managing changes to the information stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense